# Detecting client presence over websocket in cluster

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm implementing a nodejs server that uses primus to handle websocket connections. The server needs to track the presence of each client - and the server is implemented as a cluster.

When a client connects, a key is set on redis to track its presence shared with the cluster, and when the client disconnects the key is updated by the same thread.
In the event that one thread of the cluster crashes, it's clear that all the connections to that thread will be dropped.
In that scenario how do I update the status in redis for each disconnected client?

would it make sense to track the thread death on the master?

```
cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
  //.. set as disconnected all the clients for this worker in redis
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the Primus plugin that we've developed for these scenarios:

https://github.com/primus/metroplex

It also uses Redis to store the connections, but has way of clearing up servers when they are dropped from the cluster. This plugin is also officially supported by the folks who build Primus (which includes me ;-))